# Identifying most useful domain-specific tokens for adding to the existing tokenizer in huggingface transformers

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, tokenize, huggingface-tokenizers

I am using a model for token classification task on a medical domain using huggingface transformers. Unfortunately, I don’t have enough data to set up a new tokenizer and train a new model from scratch, so I am using the existing bert-based model and fine-tuning it. I want, however, to add some domain-specific words/tokens to boost the performance.

My initial thought was to make a new WordPiece tokenizer with limited vocabulary size on the medical domain and add tokens to the pre-trained tokenizer that are missing from there. However, I came up with [this article](https://medium.com/@pierre_guillou/nlp-how-to-add-a-domain-specific-vocabulary-new-tokens-to-a-subword-tokenizer-already-trained-33ab15613a41) that suggests to use `SpaCy` tokenizer with sklearn's `TfidfVectorizer` and add only words, rather than tokens, as the new tokens might mess up the existing logic of the pre-trained tokenizer.

Any suggestion of which approach might be better?